# Word 2007 VSTO wants to intercept certain document changes

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, ms-office

I have developed Word 2007 VSTO in VS2010 using C#. I want to be able to receive notifications about some of `Document`'s collection changes, e.g. `InlineShapes`. I am also eager to intercept (be notified of) Insert/Picture or when a file is being dragged and dropped onto a `Document`. Is that possible?

I have spent a significant time looking for solution and searching resources everywhere but to no avail. It seems Outlook allows more flexibility in this area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not possible. Word doesn't expose any events like that. The best you can hope for is to inteercept the DocumentChanged event, and try to ferret out was was changed based on the location in the document.

That won't be particularly easy though.